# I have two similar functions while one output changes and the other doesn't

Tags: php, forms, laravel

This code uses html, php and laravel. The first one 'tk' doesn't change in value whatever i do. The second one 'ntk' does change the value but eventually my output on the webpage allways gives me checked checkboxes for some reason. Really hope someone could help me out because I really don't know how this is possible. Especially that when I enter false in $ntk than the checkbox stays unchecked.

Here's my form:

```
<?php
        $tk = Session::has('tk') ? Session::get('tk') : 1;
        var_dump($tk);
        if($tk == 1){
            $tk = 'true';
        } else {
            $tk = 'false';
        }
        $tk_name = 'tk: ';
        var_dump($tk_name);
        var_dump($tk);
        $ntk = Session::has('ntk') ? Session::get('ntk') : 0;
        var_dump($ntk);
        if($ntk == 1){
            $ntk = 'true';
        } else {
            $ntk = 'false';
        }
        $ntk_name = 'ntk: ';
        var_dump($ntk_name);
        var_dump($ntk);
    ?>
    {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'aanvullen')) }}
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    {{ Form::submit('Toepassen') }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{ Form::checkbox('tk', 1, $tk) }} Tijdkritisch (TK) <br>
                    {{ Form::checkbox('ntk', 1, $ntk) }} Niet-tijdkritisch (NTK)
                <td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    {{ Form::close() }}
```

Here's my controller code:

```
if(isset($_POST['tk']) )
    {
        $tk = $_POST['tk'];
        Session::put('tk', $tk);
    } else {
        $tk = 1;
        Session::put('tk', $tk);
    }

    if(isset($_POST['ntk']) )
    {
        $ntk = $_POST['ntk'];
        Session::put('ntk', $ntk);
    } else {
        $ntk = 0;
        Session::put('ntk', $ntk);
    }
```

Comment: You assign a different value to `$tk` and `$ntk` if the like-named variables are not set in the session. If `tk` is not set, the value of `$tk` is 1, but if `ntk` is not set, the value of `$ntk` is 0. Is the difference intentional?

Comment: Yes because I use this to create a filter. So it should set tk as 1 and ntk as 0 for my query.

Comment: am I missing something? what's up with these `'true'` and `'false'` values? These are strings with 4 and 5 bytes of length respectively, and not the boolean values `true` and `false`.

Comment: Elaborating on @Michael's point: [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using this:

```
if($tk == 1){
    $tk = 'true';
} else {
    $tk = 'false';
}
```

In this case, `$tk` is always true because `true` is `String` not a `Boolean` value and when you use `$tk` as `Boolean` value, it comes out to `true` because it's a `truthy` value, for example:

```
$tk = 'false';
echo !!$tk; // 1 = true
```

Anyways, that's the problem, your `$tk` contains a string not `Boolean` and the right way to assign a `Boolean` value is:

```
$k = TRUE; / without qoutes
```

But you don't have to assign `TRUE` or `FALSE` to `$tk` like this:

```
enter code hereif($tk == 1){
    $tk = true;
} else {
    $tk = false;
}
```

Since, `0` is a `falsy` value evaluates to `FALSE` and `1` evaluates to `TRUE` so you can directly use `$tk` like this:

```
{{ Form::checkbox('tk', 1, $tk) }}
```

Depending on the value (`1` or `0`) of `$tk` it would be either:

```
{{ Form::checkbox('tk', 1, 1) }} // Checked
{{ Form::checkbox('tk', 1, 0) }} // Unchecked
```

So, if the `$tk` contains `1` then the `checkbox` will be `checked` and if `0` then it won't be `checked`.